# adodb driver workaround on windows 64 bit

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I have to support an application that uses an access database. My development machine is running Windows XP 64 bit, which is fine, except Windowx XP 64 doesn't have an adodb driver installed, so anytime I write scripts to update the access database I have to move the database and the scripts to a 32 bit machine, RDP in, and then run the scripts and copy everything back. Its a hassle and I can't believe there isn't a better way.

Is there a better way, or is this Microsoft's no so gentle way of telling me to move everyone to SQL Server Express(which I probably should have done long ago anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What language are you writing the scripts in?  If they are just vbscript/jscript then you can run them with the 32-bit script interpreters.

From a command prompt:

```
\windows\syswow64\wscript scriptfile
\windows\syswow64\cscript scriptfile
```

This will enable them to load 32 bit in-proc COM objects, like your database drivers.